# Snowflake get rolling average with range

Tags: sql, oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to get the rolling average of three days as per sales of the item.

Below is the table info.

```
Create table sales_info(sales_date date, daily_sales float, Salesman String, City String);

alter session set DATE_INPUT_FORMAT='DD-MM-YYYY';

insert into sales_info values
('12-12-2021',12000.30,'Max','KCR'),
('12-12-2021',32.30,'Max','Crux'),
('12-12-2021',13000.30,'Max','Xray'),
('13-12-2021',14000.30,'Kyle','KCR'),
('13-12-2021',14000.30,'Kyle','Crux'),
('13-12-2021',99000.30,'Kyle','XRay'),
('14-12-2021',2340.30,'Peter','XRay'),
('14-12-2021',1200.30,'Peter','Crux'),
('14-12-2021',22000.30,'Peter','KCR'),
('15-12-2021',132000.30,'Remo','Crux'),
('15-12-2021',124000.30,'Rexy','KCR'),
('15-12-2021',120500.30,'Tom','Xray'),
('16-12-2021',122000.30,'Felis','Crux'),
('16-12-2021',120300.30,'Felis','KCR'),
('16-12-2021',120040.30,'Max','Xray'),
('17-12-2021',120005.30,'Rubert','KCR'),
('17-12-2021',120.30,'Travis','Crux'),
('18-12-2021',200.30,'Peter','XRay'),
('18-12-2021',200.30,'Peter','Crux'),
('18-12-2021',200.30,'Peter','KCR'),
('19-12-2021',200.30,'Peter','XRay'),
('19-12-2021',500.30,'Peter','KCR'),
('19-12-2021',500.30,'Peter','CRUX'),
('20-12-2021',200.30,'Peter','XRay'),
('20-12-2021',500.30,'Peter','KCR'),
('20-12-2021',500.30,'Peter','CRUX');
```

Expected result

```
Days_range              Avg_sales  items
12-12-2021_15-12-2021   somevalue  KCR
12-12-2021_15-12-2021   somevalue  Crux
12-12-2021_15-12-2021   somevalue  Xray
16-12-2021_19-12-2021   somevalue  KCR
16-12-2021_19-12-2021   somevalue  Crux
16-12-2021_19-12-2021   somevalue  Xray
20-12-2021_23-12-2021   somevalue  KCR
20-12-2021_23-12-2021   somevalue  Crux
20-12-2021_23-12-2021   somevalue  Xray
```

Till now I have tried the below query, but I am not able to create the date range neither the result looks correct to me.

```
Select sales_date, 
       salesman,
       item,
       avg(daily_sales) over (partition by item order by sales_date rows between 2 PRECEDING and current row) 
as avg
from sales_info 
where item = 'KCR' or item = 'Crux' or item = 'XRay';
```

Comment: if your is dense, and has no duplicates you can use the ROW based window functions like your example, but if you want "prior 3 days" and their are gaps in the data, or more row per day, that you are wanting then fixed rows is not valid. Then the most performant is to explode the data by 3 and then equi join on the "exact matches"

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim Thank you for your suggestion, It seems we are close but we need answer in little different way, The result can not be in incremental days but with the gap of 3 days, So the first record will be of 12-12-2021 but second record will be of 16-12-2021, That is of 3 days gap. I can use the CTE and remove the record I dont need but again. I feel there should be a better way. And no there is no gap in the record.

Comment: Okey, given your written "desired output" does not make sense, use excel and generate the value to want, and then put those in your expected output, because "3 days gap" and average, does not make sense, unless you are say get the 12th + 16th value and divide by 2, because there are only two values? At which point that is even simpler..

Comment: Instead of "somevalue", can you show actual values that you are expecting to get?

Answer (score 0):

So I am going to use a CTE to pretend to be the table, to make life simple for me.

Then we get each row of data cross join it to three values so we can say how each could be mapped to these window dates for future days (because the window is look back). Then we join the base data, to the windows dated data, and now we have all the data the would be in the window.

The main trick to note, if you are going to sum "all sales for the last three days" the dates you join to will want to be the distinct dates for the date you are caring about, which you data as shown is respecting.

So then we can average the results, I included sum & count AND restricted the results to `Crux` to help show it was working as intented:

```
with data(date, daily_sales, sales_person, item) as (
    select * from values
    ('2021-12-12'::date,12000.30,'Max','KCR'),
    ('2021-12-12'::date,32.30,'Max','Crux'),
    ('2021-12-12'::date,13000.30,'Max','Xray'),
    ('2021-12-13'::date,14000.30,'Kyle','KCR'),
    ('2021-12-13'::date,14000.30,'Kyle','Crux'),
    ('2021-12-13'::date,99000.30,'Kyle','XRay'),
    ('2021-12-14'::date,2340.30,'Peter','XRay'),
    ('2021-12-14'::date,1200.30,'Peter','Crux'),
    ('2021-12-14'::date,22000.30,'Peter','KCR'),
    ('2021-12-15'::date,132000.30,'Remo','Crux'),
    ('2021-12-15'::date,124000.30,'Rexy','KCR'),
    ('2021-12-15'::date,120500.30,'Tom','Xray'),
    ('2021-12-16'::date,122000.30,'Felis','Crux'),
    ('2021-12-16'::date,120300.30,'Felis','KCR'),
    ('2021-12-16'::date,120040.30,'Max','Xray'),
    ('2021-12-17'::date,120005.30,'Rubert','KCR'),
    ('2021-12-17'::date,120.30,'Travis','Crux'),
    ('2021-12-18'::date,200.30,'Peter','XRay'),
    ('2021-12-18'::date,200.30,'Peter','Crux'),
    ('2021-12-18'::date,200.30,'Peter','KCR'),
    ('2021-12-19'::date,200.30,'Peter','XRay'),
    ('2021-12-19'::date,500.30,'Peter','KCR'),
    ('2021-12-19'::date,500.30,'Peter','CRUX'),
    ('2021-12-20'::date,200.30,'Peter','XRay'),
    ('2021-12-20'::date,500.30,'Peter','KCR'),
    ('2021-12-20'::date,500.30,'Peter','CRUX')
), enriched_window as (
    select 
        d.*
        ,dateadd('days', w.rn, date) as win_date
    from data as d
    cross join (
        select $1 as rn from values (0),(1),(2)
    ) as w
)
select d.date
    ,d.item
    ,avg(ew.daily_sales) as avg_sales
    ,sum(ew.daily_sales) as sum_sales
    ,count(ew.daily_sales) as count_sales
from data as d
join enriched_window as ew
    on d.date = ew.win_date
      and d.item = ew.item
      and d.item = 'Crux' -- REMOVE THIS LINE
group by 1,2
order by 1,2;
```

[image]

So if you remove the lines:

```
    ,sum(ew.daily_sales) as sum_sales
    ,count(ew.daily_sales) as count_sales
```

and

```
and d.item = 'Crux'
```

you get the expected results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, use a `RANGE` window:

```sql
SELECT sales_date,
       AVG(daily_sales) OVER (
         PARTITION BY city
         ORDER BY sales_date
         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '2' DAY PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '0' DAY FOLLOWING
       ) AS avg,
       city
FROM   sales_info 
WHERE  city IN ('KCR', 'Crux', 'XRay');
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sales_info(
  sales_date date,
  daily_sales NUMBER(10,2),
  Salesman    VARCHAR2(20),
  City        VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO sales_info ( sales_date, daily_sales, salesman, city) VALUES
(DATE '2021-12-12',  12000.30, 'Max',   'KCR'),
(DATE '2021-12-12',     32.30, 'Max',   'Crux'),
(DATE '2021-12-12',  13000.30, 'Max',   'Xray'),
(DATE '2021-12-13',  14000.30, 'Kyle',  'KCR'),
(DATE '2021-12-13',  14000.30, 'Kyle',  'Crux'),
(DATE '2021-12-13',  99000.30, 'Kyle',  'XRay'),
(DATE '2021-12-14',   2340.30, 'Peter', 'XRay'),
(DATE '2021-12-14',   1200.30, 'Peter', 'Crux'),
(DATE '2021-12-14',  22000.30, 'Peter', 'KCR'),
(DATE '2021-12-15', 132000.30, 'Remo',  'Crux'),
(DATE '2021-12-15', 124000.30, 'Rexy',  'KCR'),
(DATE '2021-12-15', 120500.30, 'Tom',   'Xray'),
(DATE '2021-12-16', 122000.30, 'Felis', 'Crux'),
(DATE '2021-12-16', 120300.30, 'Felis', 'KCR'),
(DATE '2021-12-16', 120040.30, 'Max',   'Xray'),
(DATE '2021-12-17', 120005.30, 'Rubert','KCR'),
(DATE '2021-12-17',    120.30, 'Travis','Crux'),
(DATE '2021-12-18',    200.30, 'Peter', 'XRay'),
(DATE '2021-12-18',    200.30, 'Peter', 'Crux'),
(DATE '2021-12-18',    200.30, 'Peter', 'KCR'),
(DATE '2021-12-19',    200.30, 'Peter', 'XRay'),
(DATE '2021-12-19',    500.30, 'Peter', 'KCR'),
(DATE '2021-12-19',    500.30, 'Peter', 'CRUX'),
(DATE '2021-12-20',    200.30, 'Peter', 'XRay'),
(DATE '2021-12-20',    500.30, 'Peter', 'KCR'),
(DATE '2021-12-20',    500.30, 'Peter', 'CRUX');
```

Outputs:

| SALES_DATE | AVG | CITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-12 00:00:00 | 32.3 | Crux |
| 2021-12-13 00:00:00 | 7016.3 | Crux |
| 2021-12-14 00:00:00 | 5077.633333333333333333333333333333333333 | Crux |
| 2021-12-15 00:00:00 | 49066.9666666666666666666666666666666667 | Crux |
| 2021-12-16 00:00:00 | 85066.9666666666666666666666666666666667 | Crux |
| 2021-12-17 00:00:00 | 84706.9666666666666666666666666666666667 | Crux |
| 2021-12-18 00:00:00 | 40773.6333333333333333333333333333333333 | Crux |
| 2021-12-12 00:00:00 | 12000.3 | KCR |
| 2021-12-13 00:00:00 | 13000.3 | KCR |
| 2021-12-14 00:00:00 | 16000.3 | KCR |
| 2021-12-15 00:00:00 | 53333.6333333333333333333333333333333333 | KCR |
| 2021-12-16 00:00:00 | 88766.9666666666666666666666666666666667 | KCR |
| 2021-12-17 00:00:00 | 121435.3 | KCR |
| 2021-12-18 00:00:00 | 80168.6333333333333333333333333333333333 | KCR |
| 2021-12-19 00:00:00 | 40235.3 | KCR |
| 2021-12-20 00:00:00 | 400.3 | KCR |
| 2021-12-13 00:00:00 | 99000.3 | XRay |
| 2021-12-14 00:00:00 | 50670.3 | XRay |
| 2021-12-18 00:00:00 | 200.3 | XRay |
| 2021-12-19 00:00:00 | 200.3 | XRay |
| 2021-12-20 00:00:00 | 200.3 | XRay |

---

If you want every 3rd day's values then:

```
SELECT sales_date,
       avg,
       city
FROM   (
  SELECT sales_date,
         AVG(daily_sales) OVER (
           PARTITION BY city
           ORDER BY sales_date
           RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '2' DAY PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '0' DAY FOLLOWING
         ) AS avg,
         city,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sales_date) AS rnk
  FROM   sales_info 
  WHERE  city IN ('KCR', 'Crux', 'XRay')
)
WHERE  MOD(rnk, 3) = 1;
```

| SALES_DATE | AVG | CITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-12 00:00:00 | 32.3 | Crux |
| 2021-12-12 00:00:00 | 12000.3 | KCR |
| 2021-12-15 00:00:00 | 49066.9666666666666666666666666666666667 | Crux |
| 2021-12-15 00:00:00 | 53333.6333333333333333333333333333333333 | KCR |
| 2021-12-18 00:00:00 | 80168.6333333333333333333333333333333333 | KCR |
| 2021-12-18 00:00:00 | 200.3 | XRay |
| 2021-12-18 00:00:00 | 40773.6333333333333333333333333333333333 | Crux |

---

If you want all the days and cities, including zero values when there is no data for a 3-day period then you can use a row-generator to generate the days and list the cities and then, from Oracle 12, you can use a `LATERAL` join to get the average:

```sql
WITH days (day, last_day) AS (
  SELECT MIN(sales_date) /* + INTERVAL '2' DAY */ AS min_date,
         MAX(sales_date) AS max_date
  FROM   sales_info 
  WHERE  city IN ('KCR', 'Crux', 'XRay')
UNION ALL
  SELECT day + INTERVAL '3' DAY,
         last_day
  FROM   days
  WHERE  day < last_day
),
cities (city) AS (
  SELECT 'KCR'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Crux' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'XRay' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT d.day AS sales_date,
       s.avg, 
       c.city
FROM   days d
       CROSS JOIN cities c
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
         SELECT COALESCE(AVG(daily_sales), 0) AS avg
         FROM   sales_info s
         WHERE  s.city = c.city
         AND    s.sales_date >= d.day - INTERVAL '2' DAY
         AND    s.sales_date <  d.day + INTERVAL '1' DAY
       ) s
```

Which outputs:

| SALES_DATE | AVG | CITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-12 00:00:00 | 12000.3 | KCR |
| 2021-12-12 00:00:00 | 32.3 | Crux |
| 2021-12-12 00:00:00 | 0 | XRay |
| 2021-12-15 00:00:00 | 53333.6333333333333333333333333333333333 | KCR |
| 2021-12-15 00:00:00 | 49066.9666666666666666666666666666666667 | Crux |
| 2021-12-15 00:00:00 | 50670.3 | XRay |
| 2021-12-18 00:00:00 | 80168.6333333333333333333333333333333333 | KCR |
| 2021-12-18 00:00:00 | 40773.6333333333333333333333333333333333 | Crux |
| 2021-12-18 00:00:00 | 200.3 | XRay |
| 2021-12-21 00:00:00 | 500.3 | KCR |
| 2021-12-21 00:00:00 | 0 | Crux |
| 2021-12-21 00:00:00 | 200.3 | XRay |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/G-J9ZJGp)